# xamarin.android - OnKeyLongPress does not trigger

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I want to use OnKeyLongPress on volume buttons, to override system volume control.

I am trying to use OnKeyLongPress event listener, but it's not working.

here is my code:

```
public override bool OnKeyLongPress(Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
{
    if (keyCode == Keycode.VolumeDown)
    {

        return true;
    }

    if (keyCode == Keycode.VolumeUp )
    {

        return true;
    }


    return base.OnKeyLongPress(keyCode, e);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. You need to detect the same key event in the onKeyPress handler and start tracking it so that the long press can work. Here's the code you need:

```
public override bool OnKeyDown(Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
{
    if (keyCode == Keycode.VolumeDown)
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (keyCode == Keycode.VolumeUp )
    {
        return true;
    }
    return base.OnKeyDown(keyCode, e);
}
```

Comment: I have another doubt.. method override correctly  but if i try `Console.WriteLine("test");` it doesnt react.. ;/ would u like to help?